# SQL Join taking too much time to run

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This query shown below is taking almost 2 hrs to run and I want to reduce the execution time of this query. Any help would be really helpful for me.

Currently:

```
If Exists (Select 1                                
           From PRODUCTS prd                                
           Join STORE_RANGE_GRP_MATCH srg On prd.Store_Range_Grp_Id = srg.Orig_Store_Range_Grp_ID          
                                          And srg.Match_Flag = 'Y'
                                          And prd.Range_Event_Id = srg.LAR_Range_Event_Id
           Where srg.Range_Event_Id Not IN (Select distinct Range_Event_Id
                                            From Last_Authorised_Range)
          )
```

I have tried replacing the `Not IN` clause by `Not Exists` and `Left join` but no luck in runtime execution.

What I have used:

```
If Exists(   Select top 1 *                           
      From PRODUCTS prd                               
      Join STORE srg                             
      On  prd.Store_Range_Grp_Id = srg.Orig_Store_Range_Grp_ID                                
      And  srg.Match_Flag  = 'Y'                                
      And  prd.Range_Event_Id = srg.LAR_Range_Event_Id 
and           srg.Range_Event_Id ='45655'        



Where NOT EXISTS (Select top 1 *                                  
       From Last_Authorised_Range where Range_Event_Id=srg.Range_Event_Id)                             
 )
```

`Product` table has 432837 records and the `Store` table also has almost the same number of records. This table I am creating in the stored procedure itself and then dropping it in the end in the stored procedure.

```
Create Table PRODUCTS                                 
(                                
     Range_Event_Id int,                                 
     Store_Range_Grp_Id int,                                
     Ranging_Prod_No nvarchar(14) collate database_default,
     Space_Break_Code nchar(1) collate database_default
)                     

Create Clustered Index Idx_tmpLAR_PRODUCTS 
   ON PRODUCTS (Range_Event_Id, Ranging_Prod_No, Store_Range_Grp_Id, Space_Break_Code)
```

Should I use non clustered index on this table or what all can I do to lessen the execution time? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the `PRIMARY KEY` in `PRODUCTS`?

Comment: put the result of `Select distinct Range_Event_Id                                
           From Last_Authorised_Range` in a table variable and use not exists on that.

Comment: Remove `top 1` and/or `distinct` clauses - `exists()` and `in()` work better without these. You can use `select *` instead of `select 1` - much better readability; SQL optimizer generates identical query plans for these. Create indexes on all ID fields.

Comment: Try rewriting `Where srg.Range_Event_Id Not IN (Select distinct Range_Event_Id From Last_Authorised_Range` as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN Last_Authorised_Range ON Range_Event_Id = srg.Range_Event_Id` and change the `WHERE` clause too `WHERE Range_Event_Id IS NULL`.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on other tables?

Comment: which table u are saying?

Comment: @Lankymart primary key is really required?

Comment: You decide... [Is a Primary Key necessary in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3459429/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart do u really think execution time of the query will reduce by having primary key in the table?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `top 1` or `distinct` in `exists` and `in` subqueries.  But this shouldn't affect performance.

This is the query, slightly re-arranged so I can understand it better:

```
Select 1                          
From PRODUCTS prd Join
     STORE srg                             
     On prd.Store_Range_Grp_Id = srg.Orig_Store_Range_Grp_ID and
        prd.Range_Event_Id = srg.LAR_Range_Event_Id                             
Where srg.Match_Flag  = 'Y'                                
      srg.Range_Event_Id = 45655 and   
Where NOT EXISTS (Select 1                                
                  From Last_Authorised_Range lar
                  where lar.Range_Event_Id = srg.Range_Event_Id)                             
                 )
```

Do note that I removed the double quotes around `45655`.  I presume this column is actually a number.  If so, don't confuse yourself and the optimizer by using a string for the comparison.

Then, try indexes.  I think the best indexes are:

- `store(Range_Event_Id, Match_Flag, Orig_Store_Range_Grp_ID, LAR_Range_Event_Id)`
- `products(Store_Range_Grp_Id, Range_Event_Id)` (or any index, clustered or otherwise, that starts with these two columns in either order)
- `Last_Authorised_Range(Range_Event_Id)`

From what you describe as the volume of data, your query should not be taking hours.  I think indexes can help.

Comment: I have used indexes as well and implemented left outer join by removing Not In Clause but it is still taking 2 hrs to run.

Comment: As of now i am using clustered index on all the tables which are getting used, should i change clustered index to non clustered? If yes why???

Comment: @SumitDwivedi . . . You have tried the indexes mentioned in this answer?