# Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserInfo'. The duplicate key value is (). The statement has been terminated

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

In my asp website i have a register form that sends data to the database. When a user enters his data, after submitting, an error is appeared that says:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__UserInfo__737584F762CC8D9B'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserInfo'. The duplicate key value is ().
>   The statement has been terminated.

This is the code:`
 signup.aspx.cs-

```
 protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Request.Form["name"];
    string email = Request.Form["email"];
    string password = Request.Form["password"];
    string fileName = "Database.mdf";
    string sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo VALUES('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + password + "')";
    MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(fileName,sql);
}
```

MyAdoHelper.DoQuery-

```
public static void DoQuery(string fileName, string sql)
{

    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    com.Dispose();
    conn.Close();

}
```

MyAdoHelper.ConnectToDb-

```
public static SqlConnection ConnectToDb(string fileName)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/");
    path += fileName;
    //string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/" + fileName);
    string connString = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite6\App_Data\Database.mdf; Integrated Security = True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    return conn;

}
```

Can someone help me?
thx!

Comment: which column are primary key in Userinfo talbe?

Comment: I think that name
it says PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Name] ASC)

Comment: cool so name is primary column for you ! so you need to follow as          string sql = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM USERINFO WHERE Name='"+name +"' ) BEGIN INSERT INTO UserInfo VALUES('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + password + "') END ";    As it will help you check whether that name is already present in your table or not and it will avoid you that error!

Comment: go to management studio explore database open your database and explore the table and right click on your table from dropdown click on Design when open then upload image of that

Comment: Please read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4b5973e87d0d1202f6f3fcf40de3a517

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4b5973e87d0d1202f6f3fcf40de3a517

Comment: Thx alot for the info about sql injections but i wont upload the website to the internet so i dont think its neccecry(correct me if im wrong)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but: **use parameterized queries!!**

Comment: drop the table and recreate again from given script and then check

Comment: What do you given script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your schema, but my guess is that your `email` variable is empty.

It looks like you've got a unique key set up in your SQL Server instance, and you're trying to populate that column with an empty value, for the second time.

Try double-checking each variable by adding a breakpoint when you build your queries, to ensure the client is passing data up in the same format as you expect to receive it.

Comment: I dont understand,Why would you think the email varibale is empty

Comment: @OplItay That was a bit of a stretch, but I'm hazarding the guess that email is the column with a unique key on it. It is also possible that it's one of the others.

Comment: Can you describe your schema so we can help you? Side note: I think it is time to start using some sort of ORM or at least sanitize user input. Seeing how you interact with your data layer is frightening

Comment: Oh ok thx, But could you please explain again what should i do? Im not that good in sql

Comment: Since you are new to this I would suggest the least possible effort which is validate the user input against SQL injection ... The correct approach is use prepared statements or an ORM. Btw this is not why you are getting the error...if you just want to solve that describe your schema and we can help you

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo] (
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Name] ASC)
);

This is the scema

Comment: Its says that my primary key is name
What does it mean?

Comment: That you cannot have the same name twice

Answer (score 0):

As per the error it states that you are trying to insert same value in primary key enabled column which will not allowed as it will hold only unique value.

So you can try below steps:

Check table schema and identify which column is primary column either 'name' and 'email' (not sure exact column name here) and then debug which same value is inserting multiple time.

You can also check if user is primary key then in backend change code as if that user already exists then don't insert it again else update

If email is primary key then check for it!

you can check before insert data

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from tablename where primarycolumn=value)
BEGIN
//insert into this table
END
ELSE
//update it
```

Comment: Im sorry i really dont know alot about sql. 
How do i check primary colum ?
What is primary key?

Comment: cool so name is primary column for you ! so you need to follow as   string sql = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM USERINFO WHERE Name='"+name +"' ) BEGIN INSERT INTO UserInfo VALUES('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + password + "') END ";  As it will help you check whether that name is already present in your table or not and it will avoid you that error!

Comment: I've done it, its not showing an error(thx god) but i dont think its insert the data to the table

Comment: If user already exists it will not insert data. it's because you are avoiding duplicate data in primary key column but you can update it those data!

Comment: I deleted the primary key so now its :
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo] (
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

Comment: Is primary key is really neccesery ?

Comment: There is same discussion on this in SO please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459429/is-a-primary-key-necessary-in-sql-server

Comment: Regarding your question of PK is really necessary...I would say in your case since it is a registration form I would use the email as a PK to ensure that only one registration per email is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I saved my excel import file into CSV but still weren’t able to do it until I renamed first column from ID to something else, otherwise the file is in SYLK format which resulted in this error..

https://annalear.ca/2010/06/10/why-excel-thinks-your-csv-is-a-sylk/

Answer (score 0):

A hackish way I utilized was simply not to make my unique identifier `Username` a primary key in the first place, by going to Server Explorer->Data Connections->[My Connection String]->[My Table] and then getting rid of the "PRIMARY KEY" in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Entity Framework core. What I have done is resetting the identity seed by using the following script.

```
Declare @Id int
set @Id = (You can use a value greater than the maximum existing value of the primary key column)

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Your Table Name]', RESEED, @Id);
GO
```