# Calling Stored Procedures of SQL Server with compound tables without Primary Key (ID), using Spring Data JPA

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures

I received a StoredProcedure of **SQL Server** as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_query_client
(
        @sIdClient  INT, 
        @iCodFamily     INT=NULL
        
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    IF ( @iCodFamily IS NULL )

        SELECT  c.creation_date,
            c.id_client, 
            c.dv_client,
            c.cod_family_prod,
            f.desc_family,
            c.qty_product,
            c.balance

        FROM    client_table    c,
                fammily_table   f

        WHERE   c.id_client = @sIdClient
        AND     f.cod_family_prod = c.cod_family_prod
            
    ELSE
    
        SELECT  c.creation_date,
            c.id_client, 
            c.dv_client,
            c.cod_family_prod,
            f.desc_family,
            c.qty_product,
            c.balance

        FROM    client_table    c,
                fammily_table   f

        WHERE   c.id_client = @sIdClient
        AND     c.cod_family_prod = @iCodFamily
        AND     f.cod_family_prod = c.cod_family_prod


    RETURN 0
    
END
```

As you can see this procedure is not retrieving an entity (else *compound of fields/columns from different tables*).

And its table are:

```
CREATE TABLE Database_name.dbo.client_table (
    creation_date datetime NOT NULL,
    id_client int NOT NULL,
    dv_client char(1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    cod_family_prod int NOT NULL,
    qty_product int NULL,
    balance bigint NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE database_name.dbo.fammily_table (
    cod_family_prod int NOT NULL,
    desc_family varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
);
```

As you can see the *tables are made without ID* (without primary key) as [Is a Primary Key necessary in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459429/is-a-primary-key-necessary-in-sql-server) question.

**EDIT:**
Populating the tables:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[client_table] 
    ([creation_date], [id_client], [dv_client], [cod_family_prod], [qty_product], [balance])
     VALUES
     (convert(datetime,'06/18/2001 10:34:09 PM',101), 1000 ,'1' ,1 ,1 ,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[client_table] 
    ([creation_date], [id_client], [dv_client], [cod_family_prod], [qty_product], [balance])
     VALUES
     (convert(datetime,'06/18/2002 10:34:09 PM',101), 2000 ,'1' ,1 ,1 ,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[client_table] 
    ([creation_date], [id_client], [dv_client], [cod_family_prod], [qty_product], [balance])
     VALUES
     (convert(datetime,'06/18/2003 10:34:09 PM',101), 2000 ,'3' ,2 ,1 ,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[client_table] 
    ([creation_date], [id_client], [dv_client], [cod_family_prod], [qty_product], [balance])
     VALUES
     (convert(datetime,'06/18/2004 10:34:09 PM',101), 2000 ,'3' ,2 ,1 ,4)



INSERT INTO [dbo].[fammily_table]
           ([cod_family_prod], [desc_family])
     VALUES
           (1, 'one')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[fammily_table]
           ([cod_family_prod], [desc_family])
     VALUES
           (2, 'two')
```

Calling the procedure

```
EXEC sp_query_client @sIdClient = 1000, @iCodFamily = 1;

EXEC sp_query_client @sIdClient = 2000;
```

[image]

Due to I need to **call** the `Stored Procedure` using `Spring Data JPA`, I was reading these posts:

- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-stored-procedures (In the used example
  the ID is required)
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures  (In the
  used example the ID is required)
- https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2018/04/25/invocar-a-procedimientos-usando-spring-boot-data-jpa/
  (That uses an interface extending from `CrudRepository` that needs an
  ID and `@Procedure` annotation).

But, those posts aren't covering compound select (multiple columns from different tables)

My Question is: **How I must call my procedure (using Spring Boot, JPA) when there aren't defined single entities (else compound fields from different tables) and there aren't ID (Primary Key) for them?**

Example using `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` or `createStoredProcedureQuery` from `javax.persistence.EntityManager`

Comment: 'As you can see' - I can't, please add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: @p-salmon Unfortunately I can't place real tables/storedProcedure/data. I made a mimic of my situation (tables without ID's - Primary Key) and multiple fields of multiple tables. I place data according to my mimic tables.